# On button1 click create variable and on button2 click use that variable created in the button1 | C# WPF

Tags: c#

I have the following `button1` *Click* method:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string createstringvalue = MyCustomMethod();
}
```

When the user clicks the `button1` it generates a custom `string`.

I want to use this custom `string` as an argument in a custom method used by the `button2` *Click* method.

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
   bool commandExecuted = CustomMethod2(createstringvalue);

   if (commandExecuted)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
   }
}
```

Currently I get an ERROR:

> The name `createstringvalue` does not exist in the current context

I apologize if my question is quite simple. I try to learn C# , so I try different concepts.

Please mark the question as duplicate, and I will close it, if it is already answered and post in the comments the duplicate SO question.

Comment: Make it a private variable inside your class.

Comment: @Loocid you mean something like: ```public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string connectionString;```

Comment: Yep, that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a variable outside your click event as Loocid mentioned, or you can directly read the value in button2:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  
            bool commandExecuted = CustomMethod2(MyCustomMethod());

            if (commandExecuted)  //or:  if (CustomMethod2(MyCustomMethod()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected file was loaded successfully");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey, Peter thanks a lot for your answer. It is a valid one so I will acknowledge. But I have a reason to call two different button click because "MyCustomMethod" opens a new window in my application. So If I call it again inside button2 click will open again a pop up window. I did not include that information in my question so I acknowledge and upvote your answer because it is error free and a valid one. :)

Comment: Hey Peter, sorry for the long delay. I have accepted your answer :)

Comment: @NikSp no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the class `string createstringvalue;` Define the variable as

later

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   createstringvalue = MyCustomMethod();
}
```

Comment: Hey Oguzhan thanks for your answer. You probably missed something? Its seems incomplete :)